# Macro with show messsage box if cell contains value

Tags: vba, excel, macros, msgbox

I would like to do a macro. My testing cells are on another sheet. Sheet - (data) Macro check a range `("D2:D10")` if the cells contain value 12 if yes show me a message box `"Go to add to system"` and this cell where macro found a value will be set to 0.

I have this code but it doesn't work for me I don't known why. Can you help me?

```
Private Sub check(ByVal Target As Range)
For Each c In Worksheet("data").Range("D2:D10")
 If Range("D2:D10") = 12 Then
    MsgBox "Go to add to system"
    Range ("D2:D10").value = 0
 End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: What if multiple cells have 12? Do you want to change the full range to 0 if even one cell is found 12?

Comment: multiple or only one it does not matter

Comment: @Fiínek Cahů  test the code in my answer below and let me know is it works like you intended

Comment: @FiínekCahů nothing ? no feedback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will correct your code (it will run without errors):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub check(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c   As Range

For Each c In Worksheets("data").Range("D2:D10")
    If c.Value = 12 Then
        MsgBox "Go to add to system"
        c.Value = 0
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

However, you could go with a slightly different approach - by accomplishing what you are trying to achieve in the `Worksheet_Change` event (of "data" sheet).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c   As Range

' Optional : use if criteria below to check the range only
' if one of the cells inside range("D2:D10") has changed
If Not Intersect(Range("D2:D10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    ' if you decide to use the "If"above, then you don't need the "For" loop below
    For Each c In Range("D2:D10") 
        If c.Value = 12 Then
            MsgBox "Go to add to system"
            c.Value = 0
        End If
    Next c
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, please can you help me replace range for specific cells ? or can I use both method together? thx

Comment: @FiínekCahů  what is the specific cell? You can use a range also for a single cell.

Comment: not range but specific cells such as "D29","D55" etc.

Comment: you can use range also for these, use `Range("D29,D55")` etc.

Comment: I try to use similar code, please look to this page: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163346/macro-range-specific-cells-msg-box [/link]