# macro range / specific cells msg box

Tags: excel, vba, macros, msgbox

can you help me with macro please? I have a 3 code which show me msg box only if - specific value. But dont work for me. :/ I dont known why. some errors, I would like to make all ranges and after show me msgbox when value be fulfill. Someone known?

NOW I HAVE BUT SHOW ME ERROR SEE IMAGE

```
Public Sub found(worksheets)

Dim found As Boolean
Dim c   As Range

found = False
For Each c In worksheets("data").Range("D155,D456,D757,D1058,D1359,D1660,D1961:D1964,D36811,D36813,D38015,D38617,D39219,D39821,D40423,D41025,D52576,D53178,D54984,D55586,D56790,D57392,D58897")

    If c.Value = 8 Then
        found = True
        c.Value = -1
    End If
Next
If found Then MsgBox ("    ZAHLASTE BALENÍ !!!") & vbCrLf & ("BALÍCÍ MNOŽSTVÍ JE 15 KS")

found = False
For Each c In worksheets("data").Range("D29,D31,D33,D35,D37,D39,D41,D43,D45,D47,D49,D51:D57,D59,D61,D63,D65,D67:D83,D85,D87,D89,D91:D95,D97:D101,D103,D105,D107,D109,D110:D111,D41944,D42246:D42250,D45263,D45265,D45267,D45269,D45271,D45273,D45275,D45277,D45279,D45280,D45581,D45882,D46183,D46484,D46785,D47086,D47387")

    If c.Value = 5 Then
        found = True
        c.Value = -1
    End If
Next
If found Then MsgBox ("    ZAHLASTE BALENÍ") & vbCrLf & ("BALÍCÍ MNOŽSTVÍ JE 6 KS")

found = False
For Each c In worksheets("data").Range("D3165,D3466,D3767,D4068,D4369,D4670,D4971,D5272,D5573,D5874,D6175:D10088,D10389,D10690,D41643,D41945,D42251,D42552,D42853,D43154,D43455,D43755,D44057,D44357,D44658,D44959,D48892,D49193,D49494,D49795,D50097,D50397,D50698,D50999,D51308:D51339")

    If c.Value = 8 Then
        found = True
        c.Value = -1
    End If
Next
If found Then MsgBox ("    ZAHLASTE BALENÍ") & vbCrLf & ("BALÍCÍ MNOŽSTVÍ JE 9 KS")

End Sub
```

In next sheet i call `Call Module1.check(worksheets)`

this part of code show me error.
           [image]

Comment: modify your `.Range("D155:D155", "D456:D456", "D757:D757", "D1058:D758",....)` to ``.Range("D155, D456, D757, D1058" ....)`  . You need to make sure your `Range`s are valid. The `"` are in the begining and the end of the brackets `( )`

Comment: if your `worksheets` argument is actual `Worksheets` collection of `Workbook` object then you'd better pass your function a `workbook` object (i.e.: `Public Sub check(wb As Workbook)`) and then use `For Each c In wb.Worksheets("data")`, just not to mess up with built in objects names

Comment: ok i try to change, first part of code is good but second part show me error in this part:                                                                                             For Each c In worksheets("data").Range("D29,D31,D33,D35,D37,D39,D41,D43,D45,D47,D49,D51:D57,D59,

Comment: please edit the question to post your updated code, and state precisely the error message.

Comment: please see the last part of my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to applying the comments above (especially use `"D155"` instead of `"D155:D155"`, etc,

Here's how you can display the msgbox only once after the completeness of each operation:

```
Dim found as Boolean

found = false
For Each c In worksheets("data").Range(...)
    If c.Value = 8 Then
        found = True
        c.Value = -1
    End If
Next
If found then MsgBox ("    ZAHLASTE BALENÍ !!!") & vbCrLf & ("BALÍCÍ MNOŽSTVÍ JE 15 KS")

found = false
For Each c In worksheets("data").Range(...)
    If c.Value = 5 Then
        found = True
        c.Value = -1
    End If
Next
If found then MsgBox ("    ZAHLASTE BALENÍ") & vbCrLf & ("BALÍCÍ MNOŽSTVÍ JE 6 KS")

found = false
For Each c In worksheets("data").Range(...)
    If c.Value = 8 Then
        found = True
        c.Value = -1
    End If
Next
If found then MsgBox ("    ZAHLASTE BALENÍ") & vbCrLf & ("BALÍCÍ MNOŽSTVÍ JE 9 KS")
```

**EDIT: the next problem**

The method `Range` will fail if the length of the submitted string is too long, more than 255 characters. You can workaround it by splitting the specification of the range in two parts:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = worksheets("data").Range("D29,D31,D33,D35,D37,D39,D41,D43,D45,D47,D49,D51:D57,D59,D61,D63,D65,D67:D83,D85,D87,D89,D91:D95,D97:D101,D103,D105,D107,D109,D110:D111,D41944,D42246:D42250,D45263,D45265,D45267,D45269,D45271,D45273")
Set r = Union(r, worksheets("data").Range("D45275,D45277,D45279,D45280,D45581,D45882,D46183,D46484,D46785,D47086,D47387"))
For Each d in r  ' <-- Proceed from here
```

Comment: Thank you works perfect !! Now message box is on background and wait to click then show me on foreground how can I do msgbox only on foreground? [link] https://postimg.org/image/gf567vsnz/

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped. For the new problem, I think it is of a completely different nature, so I suggest to ask a question on its own (Excel VBA msgBox pops in Background), hopefiully somebody has faced the same problem and will give you a solution.